# How can you strike through a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

```
document.getElementById(wordArray[i]).value = answer[i] + ' ' + wordArray[i];
```

I want to strike through part answer[i], but not wordArray[i]. How should I go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strike though a variable sounds weird, do you mean to strike a text (string)?
In that case you have `text-decoration: line-through;` ([see more about text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration))

If that's the case you can wrap your variabe into a span tag, i.e.:

`'<span class="line-through">' + answer[i] + '</span>`

```css
.line-through { text-decoration: line-through }
```